# MLCP export except specific collection

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I need to export all the documents from the database except documents from specific collection.

Let's say, I have a collections called `test1` (100 docs), `test2` (200 docs) and `test3` (100 docs)

As per my requirement, I want to export all the documents from `test1` and `test2` collection and not from `test3` collections.

Is it possible to do this using MLCP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply a [`-query_filter`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_66898) with a [`cts:and-not-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-not-query) specifying the positive and negative `cts:collection-query()` queries.

```
cts:and-not-query(
 cts:collection-query(("test1","test2")),
 cts:collection-query("test3")
)
```

`-query_filter` parameter value is the query [serialized as either XML or JSON](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/cts_query#id_11229)

As XML:

```
<cts:and-not-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:positive>
    <cts:collection-query>
      <cts:uri>test1</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>test2</cts:uri>
    </cts:collection-query>
  </cts:positive>
  <cts:negative>
    <cts:collection-query>
      <cts:uri>test3</cts:uri>
    </cts:collection-query>
  </cts:negative>
</cts:and-not-query>
```

as JSON:

```
{"andNotQuery":{"positiveQuery":{"collectionQuery":{"uris":["test1", "test2"]}}, "negativeQuery":{"collectionQuery":{"uris":["test3"]}}}}
```